# Visual studio 2013 and Typescript red squiggy lines

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am using Typescript in Visual studio 2013 and when I write code, all I get is some red squiggy lines underneath the code. Attached is a screen shot. How can I correct this? The code builds anyway but its kind of annoying. 
[image]

Comment: Generally this means error. Yes, all typescript will either transpile or stay as-is and still produce a .js file but it does not mean the typescript is valid rather that that line (or lines) will be copied as is. If you want to fix the errors see what the error is and copy it to the question.

Comment: When I mouse over the const keyword all I get is "
Expression statement is not assignment or call"

Comment: It looks like you're using features of TypeScript that are not recognized by VS2013. Likely you need to upgrade your TypeScript plugin: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48739

Comment: I am running visual studio update 5 which has the most current Typescript. I  am not sure that is the reason.